# Register value not getting updated properly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have written the following assembly language program to determine if the value in **al** is a digit

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
randVal DWORD ?
.code

main PROC

IsDigit PROC
cmp al,'0'
jb ID1 
cmp al,'9'
ja ID1 
test ax,0 
ID1: ret
IsDigit ENDP

mov al, 'x'
call IsDigit
mov bl , 'y'
main ENDP
END main
```

Here is what I see in debugging mode in registers. As I have put x into al. x = 120 in ASCII = 78.
I expected to see **78 in AL**. But that's not the case : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy0rm.png)

I have defined a proc called IsDigit and then call it using **call IsDigit**. Is that a correct 
way to call an assembly language function. Also I see only the main registers in the registers window
Is there a way to see all flags too in visual studio

Comment: Why is `IsDigit` defined inside of `main` ?

Comment: It seems like you're stepping the code from the first entry into `main`, where the first thing it will do is execute `IsDigit` with uninitialized registers, since as Michael says that's where you put the code.  You probably want to move `IsDigit` outside of `main`; then it will only be called after the `mov al, 'x'`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. so `main` in assembly is also a special function name just like in other programming languages. And that is the one that will get executed first. Also what's the purpose of that last line `END main` as we have already done main ENDP

Comment: `END procId` _Marks the end of a module and, optionally, sets the program entry point to procId._   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/end-masm?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thanks. Also if you go to Debug->Wndows->Registers I do see all the register values. But I don't see the flags. Is there any window in visual studio to see flags.

Comment: Is there any better alternative to using visual studio for assembly programming ?

Comment: Isn't `EFL` the flags? The layout of this register is explain in Intel's manual, section _3.4.3  EFLAGS Register_.